# My array displays 50 elements then i get random memory sizes, why is that?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, out-of-memory, limit

If i try to input the 50th number in the series it displays until the 46th and then generates random numbers however when i counted the characters in both i found they were both equal to 10, so why does it stop at precisely 46?

My Code:

```
void calculating_f(int val){
    int aray[100] = {0,1};
    int i;

    printf("%i %i ", aray[0], aray[1]);
    for (i=2; i < val; i++){
      aray[i] = aray[i - 2] + aray[i - 1];
      printf("%i ", aray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `val`?

Comment: Show more code, especially how you call that function.

Comment: The values get too large for a 32 bit `int` at this point - consider using `uint64_t` instead.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and include the actual and expected output from that program.

Comment: As mentioned by Paul: use a larger integer type (e.g. `long`): [here's an example that you can run online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ae5db5378167854)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Answer after correction]**
Thanks to @mch for pointing out the mistake in my answer about using 'unsigned int data type'.

Please use 'unsigned long long int (64bit data type)' and '%llu' format specifier for printf() call.

**[Answer before correction]**
aray is storing int data as per definition.

When you are giving limit val = 50, then, the calculated value is exceeding the max value of signed integer data type when i = 47.

You should change data type to 'unsigned int' and use '%u' in format specifier in printf() call.

Comment: the overflow occurs with `unsigned int` at `i=48`, so it is not really an option.

Answer (score 2):

Integer overflow (assuming `int`s are 32-bits on  your system). The 46th Fibonacci number is largest that will fit into a signed 32-bit value.

BTW -- You don't really need an array for this.

Answer (score -1):

it's because you're using int, int in c can hold numbers from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, but the 47th Fibonacci number is  2971215073 which is outside that range causing an overflow.you could try using a long long which will get you up to the 92nd Fibonacci number.

p.s if you only want to get the n-th Fibonacci number there's no need for the array. look into Matrix exponentiation  if you need to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number, it's much faster than what you're doing if you only need the n-th Fibonnaci number

Comment: the 92nd number `7540113804746346429` fits into an `long long`. `double` will result in wrong numbers.